# How to show hex values in the x/y axis?

Tags: highcharts

Is there an easy way in highcharts to show hex values the x/y axis instead of decimal values?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have to tell highcharts what categories to display on the axis, you must convert the decimals to hex first:

```
var cat = [100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,1100,1200];
var hexValues = $.map(cat,function(cat){
  return cat.toString(16);
});
```

then assign them to the axis:

```
 xAxis: {
        categories: hexValues
    },
```

Comment: Got it, I was thinking of doing it this way as well just wanted to see if there was anything built in where I can simply initialize the axis with something like:

xAxis: {
            type: 'hex'
        }

But your solution will work, thanks.

Comment: @NickTran That would be nice, but I don't believe there is

Answer (score 0):

You can use also formatter() to map your values http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter